# IP Warming small email domains

Tags: marketing-cloud, email, deliverability, ip-warming

What is the best way to warm-up the email domains that only have a couple of email addresses in the database? I already did an IP Warming and the deliverability decreased a lot in the last sends that include most of these small domains.

Is it better to include it in the sent with the bigger ones (gmail, yahoo, outlook...)?

The average of recipients per send/day was 20k, for 10 days.

Comment: Was the IP + domain already warmed up when you started sending to these new email providers? How are you monitoring the deliverability?

Comment: we started from scratch, first warm-up

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The main reason for doing IP warmup is to gradually increase your volume, without hitting the daily capping limits for ISPs. I.e. you don't want to hit Hotmail with 25.000 email on the first day of sendouts. If your volumes are within 20k for all your subscribers, I will not see IP warmup as being needed.

When you talk about small domains - how many addresses are within each of them for every send? If this is within few hundreds, indeed IP warmup is not the issue. Usually those small ISPs have inferior spam algorithms, which are not as intelligent as e.g. Gmail. There is nothing else for you to do, than continuing sending to them. What you might be seeing, however, is your IP being blacklisted - something you can verify [in this tool](https://mxtoolbox.com/blacklists.aspx).

I will also recommend you keep an eye on your [SenderScore](https://senderscore.org/), giving you an indication of your overall reputation. The timeline can also provide you insights into any specific sends causing drops in reputation.

Comment: Thanks, that info is really useful. The only thing is still not clear for me is what to do with the small domains (e.g., less than 5 addresses). As they will be part of the email audiences one day, they should be part of the warm-up.

Comment: Basically, you can't warm up domains with this few addresses. IP Warmup is meant to help you achieve adequate reputation to send out [large volumes to specific ISPs](https://help.returnpath.com/hc/en-us/articles/222437587-What-is-IP-warming-and-why-do-you-need-to-do-it-). When working with domains with this few addresses, it is either or.